# PHP json decode do not give original value it is truncate

Tags: php, json

I have a string:

```
{"lat":28.67167520663993,"lng":77.23913223769534}
```

When I use:

```
$json = json_decode($json['latlng'] , true); 
echo "<pre>";print_r($json );
```

then output value is:

Array:

```
(
    [lat] => 28.67167520664
    [lng] => 77.239132237695
)
```

but result is different and truncated

I need original value how can i do it?

Comment: Also read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4265352).

Answer (score 2):

As much i understand below is my input:

1) The value you providing is `float` value. It's float problem not `json` problem. 
2) The workaround is you can wrap your value in double quotes `"28.67167520663993"`. It will give you proper output. Code shown below

```
$a = '{"lat":"28.67167520663993","lng":"77.23913223769534"}';
print_r(json_decode($a,true));
```

3) Float is going to round till `3 digit precision` by default in my system. 
4) Another method to prevent set `ini_set('precesion',15)`. It will not round up till 15 digits.

```
<?php
ini_set('precision', 15);
$a = '{"lat":28.67167520663993,"lng":77.23913223769534}';
print_r(json_decode($a,true));
```

5) Bugs already reported [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68200). Above is different way of prevention till php introduce some solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$json = '{"lat":28.67167520663993,"lng":77.23913223769534}';
$json = preg_replace('/:\s*(\-?\d+(\.\d+)?([e|E][\-|\+]\d+)?)/', ': "$1"', $json);

$jsond = json_decode($json , true); 
echo "<pre>";print_r($jsond );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's matter of numeric precision. You can't do much about that using `json_decode()` unless you want to parse JSON file yourself and use [GMP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) to handle your values.

See notes in docs: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

> **Warning**
>
> Floating point precision Floating point numbers have limited
> precision. Although it depends on the system, PHP typically uses the
> IEEE 754 double precision format, which will give a maximum relative
> error due to rounding in the order of 1.11e-16. Non elementary
> arithmetic operations may give larger errors, and, of course, error
> propagation must be considered when several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
> floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
> exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
> used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
> cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
> small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for
> example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
> expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
> 7.9999999999999991118....
>
> **So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
> compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher
> precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp
> functions are available.**